# Drupal 7 - Webform select options advice

Tags: drupal, webforms, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 webform where one of the components is selecting an email address from a list.

What is the best way / webform component to use for this?

One option I've though is adding them all into the taxonomy db table and creating a pre built list based off of a taxonomy list.

This would work but I'm expecting approx 1,000 results, so scrolling through a selection options component isn't really ideal.

Is there any sort of search and select webform component module that could be used instead of the standard select options? Or perhaps an alternative way of tackling this?

[image: Select options]

[image: Select options values]

Answer (score 0):

For 1000 results you will need to modify your webform and do something like an autocomplete. You would need something preloaded or do async requests to retrieve the results.

This modules seems that could work for your situation, it works with webform and it is stable:
https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_autocomplete

Good luck!

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I also posted this on the Drupal Answers forum and got a similar response.

The problem with Webform Autocomplete is that for a start there is a bug that doesn't allow it to work for anonymous users (only logged in users) and it also doesn't allow the autocomplete field to be used as the email to address when sending emails via the webform module.